# Bcrypt and salted passwords - clarification?

Tags: cryptography, bcrypt

I'm using the [Bcrypt nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt/) which is an encryption utility implementing the Blowfish cipher

A simple scenario is to create a hashed password + salt.

There's one thing which I don't understand about the way they've implemented it.

Example:

```
var salt= BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(12);
Console.WriteLine(salt);

var hashedPassword = BCryptHelper.HashPassword("myPassword",salt) ;
Console.WriteLine(hashedPassword);
Console.WriteLine(BCryptHelper.CheckPassword("myPassword",hashedPassword));
```

output :

```
$2a$12$RqHpb3v6MeaB5sj0wcasKO
$2a$12$RqHpb3v6MeaB5sj0wcasKO/QkBTgrfVRYk95sT.OGIdU.O/Ip4goi
True
```

In the first line, I generate salt.
Later I'm hashing a password with salt.

But look at the response, they actually adding it to the hashed password rather than adding salt , and then hash it.

Notice that you do see the salt in the hashed password:

[image]

IMHO it's not the right way to do it.
FWIW we should take a password + salt and then hash then.

For example :

[image]

You can see in the image that salt is not visible in the final result.

**Question:**

Why did they implement hash salted password like this ?  is this the right way? isn't it dangerous that salt is visible in the final result?

Comment: They _do_ hash the password and the salt. It is then prepended because to check it needs to know which salt was used previously.

Comment: This is more a question for [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) than here. Notice that this is covered already, so search before asking

Comment: @tkausl hash salt should be kept aside from the final result .

Comment: Why? You can't do with either of them (hash and salt) if you don't know the other, it makes sense to store them together.

Comment: @tkausl _You can store the salt in plaintext without any form of obfuscation or encryption, but don't just give it out to anyone who wants it._  https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17435/5001

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. You don't "give it out to anyone". Neither the hash, nor the salt. Storing them together or aside doesn't change anything, really.

Comment: @tkausl You're right. took me some time to understand that actually. :-)

Comment: @tkausl I think I know why I was confused. in general scenraious, you have the hashed salted value and a salt.  So you have two values.But in here , in bcrypt format, they merged it into one value which is understood already by bcrypt when deciphered.

Comment: @tkausl one more problematic  thing. if a user is doing login, and enters a password , then I need to salt and hash his password in order to compare it to the store value. So I need now only the salt. and I don't have it if I save it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The salt is stored together with the hash to make it possible to validate it.

Had the salt not been stored, it would be impossible to validate the hash, since you don't know the full input to the hash (which includes the salt).

The point of salt is to make each hash different; not to be secret.

Comment: Shouldn't salt be kept aside ? I'm almost positive it should

Comment: see here : https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17435/5001 - _You can store the salt in plaintext without any form of obfuscation or encryption, but don't just give it out to anyone who wants it._

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Why? The salt is no more or less sensitive than the hash, which you also "don't just give it out to anyone who wants it."

Comment: I agree that lt is mandatory. I  thought that storing it in a visible way besides the final result , is a bit problematic

Comment: I think I know why I was confused. in general scenarios, you have the hashed salted value and a salt. So you have two values.But in here , in bcrypt format, they merged it into one value which is understood already by bcrypt when deciphered.\